# How to add two variables in a function that every time the one is the working?

Tags: php

With the following function I sort the posts of RSS ascending.

`usort($posts, 'mysort');`

`function mysort($x, $y) { 
    return strtotime($y->pubDate) - strtotime($x->pubDate); 
}`

However some of those feeds have instead of a pubDate tag (for the date), they have a tag named published.

All feeds are saved ine one array. My question is how to satisfy both using my function or another function? Something like these:

`return strtotime($y->pubDate OR $y->published) - strtotime($x->pubDate OR $x->published);`

Comment: Please explain--in full sentences, written in proper English--what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: Just check your inputs, and change your outputs accordingly (in vague pseudocode):  `if($x is a pubdate tag and $y is a pubdate tag){return strtotime($y->pubDate) - strtotime($x->pubDate);}else if($x is not a pubdate tag and $y is not a pubdate tag){//do whatever you want here}`, etc etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, but is this what you what?

```
return strtotime(($y->pubDate)?$y->pubDate:$y->published) - 
                  strtotime(($x->pubDate)?$x->pubDate:$x->published);
```

Basically, I'm using a ternary IF operator that can be read like so: `(if condition)?then do this:else do this;`

Does it help?

**Edit**

Small edit based on your question about echoing the value:

The answer depends on which attribute take precedence over the other.. for instance, if pubDate it's more importante than published, then you'd write something like:

```
echo ($x->pubDate)?$x->pubDate:$x->published;
```

And if it was the other way around:

```
echo ($x->published)?$x->published:$x->pubDate;
```

(changing $x for whatever your object is called ofcourse..)

Does this help?

Comment: If it helps,  I updated my question for better understanding.

Comment: I think my answer still applies, if the pubDate attribute is available, it'll use that otherwise, it'll use the published attribute.

Comment: I am checking it now. One more thing though, how do I echo the value? I mean how to know If should I echo pubDate or published

Comment: @mtopia Edited the original answer to give a better response to your latest question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Date object and get the diff.

```
`$a = new DateTime($startDate);`
`$b = new DateTime("now");`
`return $b->diff($a);`
```